# How to create icon on desktop

Tags: unity, customization

Now these days I am customizing Ubuntu and I want some icons on my desktop in customizes OS like

1. My computer
2. Home
3. Trash

How can I create these icons on my desktop. And I am in chroot environment so I can use only terminal to do any thing with my customize OS. So please tell me how can I do that with the help of terminal.